# Match 3D point cloud to CAD model in real time

Tags: matching, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, cad

I have a point cloud of an object in the scene, obtained with depth ZED camera( in real-time), and a CAD surface model of that object. How can I match the point cloud to the CAD model, to obtain the translation and rotation between the cloud and model in real-time?

I suppose I could sample the surface and try the Iterative Closest Point (ICP) algorithm to match the resulting sampled point cloud to the CAD point cloud. Would that actually work? I was thinking to modify the registration algorithm and use this example [PCL Registration example](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/doc/tutorials/content/sources/registration_api/example2.cpp). But what should I change in order to read the ZED Camera points clouds in real-time and match with the CAD model?

And are there better algorithms for this task?
Thanks

Comment: Have the same question.